# JQGrid is not Showing "Loading" Message on Column Sort

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My JQGrid will not show the default "Loading" message when I am performing a column sort. I added the default code explicitly just to be safe:

loadui: 'enable'

but it still does not show the "Loading" message in the middle of the grid. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue myself. I removed the line

```
loadonce: true,
```

from my JQGrid properties, and that fixed the issue. Not sure why, but for now, I'll take it. Here is the info from the wiki on loadonce:

> If this flag is set to true, the grid loads the data from the server
>   only once (using the appropriate datatype). After the first request,
>   the datatype parameter is automatically changed to local and all
>   further manipulations are done on the client side. The functions of
>   the pager (if present) are disabled.

Comment: To attempt to clear things up: client-side operations do not require AJAX operations, and the loading dialog is only displayed during an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

The `loadui` option is only for grids that use AJAX operations, such as if they are loading XML or JSON data directly from an external source. From the [jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions):

> This option controls what to do when an ajax operation is in progress.

If your grid is using a local data source then you will never see the loading dialog. On the other hand, if your grid is retrieving its own data, it would help if you could provide some of your code to let us help narrow-down the problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that the Loading message shows up on the initial load of my grid data, just not when I do a column sort.

Comment: Are you using the `loadonce: true` option? That would instruct the grid to use client-side sorting instead of making an AJAX call. On the other hand, if you are using AJAX calls to do the sorting then this is *very* weird.

Comment: Ah, thanks Justin! Looks like we figured this out at about the same time. :) I commented out loadonce and it works now. (Default value of loadonce is false, and I had it set to true.)